# A safe way to get Rivet City Security Uniform?

Tags: fallout-3

In addition to collecting as many unique items as I can, late (late) in this most recent run of Fallout 3, I've been trying to get at least one sample of each kind of weapon and armor. It's not like I'm running off a list (as I am with the uniques), but if I know of something that I don't have, well, I want it.

One of those items is the Rivet City Security Uniform.

Now the obvious answer is to just whack one of the guards. And I would -- I have, in fact tried it, sneaking (fully hidden) and with a one-shot-kill weapon (MPLX Megasurge). I specifically tried to whack the guard outside Rivet City, as he seemed to be the most "exposed."

However, his compatriots (including the officer in charge of handing out water with Broken Steel) still turned red and, as soon as I stopped sneaking, opened fire.

I don't want Rivet City mad at me (at least, not until I commit [mass murder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/ramifications-of-mass-slaughter)), so what's the safest way to go about getting me some of that sweet, sweet Security Uniform goodness until then?

Comment: OH GOD ITS THAT MASS MURDERER AGAIN...EVERYBODY PANIC ;)

Comment: *coc testqaitems*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to engage in a trick known as [Reverse Pickpocketing](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Planting_items). In short, what you need to do is plant a higher quality suit of armor on the individual wearing the gear you want (measured by defense rating). They'll then equip this armor, leaving you free to pickpocket the gear they're wearing. The Metal Armor and Helmet are a good choice for this, because of their high DR value, and relative low cost. Other options include any other Combat Armor variant other than the Security Uniform, or of course, any Power Armor.

An alternative is to make use of [The Mesmetron](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mesmetron) to stun/hypnotize a guard and demand they hand over their stuff. This may end violently however.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of reverse pickpocketing, but was concerned about doing this to the generic NPCs. Will the game reload the same generic NPC when I leave/re-enter the area? (Doing so to, say, Harkness isn't an option because he's somewhere in the Commonwealth by now ... )

Comment: I'm not sure. But there are several named guards besides Harkness IIRC, and of course, if that fails, there's always the Mesmetron.

Comment: This is probably the safest way in general, if you're earlier in the game than I am. As it turned out, for me it was easiest to do while systematically slaughtering all of Rivet City ...

Answer (score 7):

If you haven't yet reached Max Level, picking up the Mr. Sandman perk will allow you to slaughter sleeping Rivet City Guards left and right, as long as you please. No one will be the wiser.

Answer (score 5):

If you've got Broken Steel, then after you recover, there are rivet city guards defending the memorial against Enclave, and they often die.

If you fast travel there, you can watch, and pick up the pieces afterwards.

Comment: Dang, too late (have long since finished BS), but that would have been the easiest way to do it!

Comment: @John Rudy AFAIK they will keep on spawning, so if you've got that far you should be able to get as many uniforms as you want. OTOH maybe they stop after you complete the BS missions?

Comment: I just waited until I committed [mass slaughter](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6518/58) and got one then. :)

Answer (score 3):

Stand on one end of the bridge to Rivet city with a good sniper rifle, kill the guards at the door, steal uniform, run, and don't come back for 3 days!

Answer (score 2):

With the mothership zeta add-on there is one crazed rivet city guard all alone,you can easily kill him(her) and take the armor.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail? Where is this NPC located?

Answer (score 0):

Killing the guard at the main door works fine. I've done it any number of times. They often fall in the water.

Try again. Maybe use a melee weapon. Those are silent.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do it is to go to the front door guard and make sure he/she is alone. Then, kill them and run away until it says you are hidden through crouching, now just use the "wait" feature and time 24 hours 3 times (which is 3 days) and now the aggression towards your player character will reset and you can roam Rivet City again freely with no hostilities. Another way to do it is to reverse-pickpocket them, just pickpocket a high-condition combat armor and helmet on them, fast travel away, and fast travel back, and now if it's the same person guarding the door they should be wearing that armor and you should be free to pickpocket them for their armor. Save often though, you can be caught many times if you're sneak skill isn't high enough and it's a bit tricky. And the last and final way to do it is to use the mesmetron from Paradise Falls and find a good angle to shoot the guard. If they're stunned, you can tell them if you can look in their pockets and take the armor from them, and you can put a slave collar on them or just take the armor and leave. I know the post is old, but I was just bored so I decided to post this. I hope this is still useful in some way...