# In Mothership Zeta, what and where are the different armor types you can acquire?

Tags: fallout-3

Because I have the Winterized Medic Armor, and the Samurai armor, but I feel as though I'm missing something. Confirmation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few other outfits to be found in Mothership Zeta:

[General Chase's Overcoat](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/General_Chase%27s_overcoat) can be found in the Waste Disposal Area, and [Paulson's Outfit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Paulson%27s_outfit) can be had if you're willing to kill Paulson, or do some [Reverse Pickpocketing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6602/a-safe-way-to-get-rivet-city-security-uniform) to get him to equip something else.

There's also the Spacesuit, but I'm assuming you've just not mentioned that, as it's something of an unmissable quest item, and also rather useless.