# Who are the Essential NPCs in The Citadel?

Tags: fallout-3

So I have begun my little [side quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/ramifications-of-mass-slaughter). I enlisted Fawkes, as I happened to start it in Underworld and realize that I had good alignment before starting. Cleared that out. Started clearing Rivet City. Will need to go home and change, because I think it will be funnier if I do this wearing the Pint-Sized Slasher Mask and Blast Off Pyjamas.

In Rivet City, though, I had an unexpected surprise: Flak is essential, and unkillable. I know there will be more essentials as I do this, and the area I'm perhaps most worried about them is The Citadel.

So who are all the essentials in The Citadel, since they're likely to be heavily armed (and armored)?

Comment: Do you realize what you've done? This is a _valid "list of..." question_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked all [Citadel characters](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Citadel_characters) and according to [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Wiki), only the following characters are essential in the [Citadel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel)

- [Arthur Maxson](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Maxson)
- [Bael](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bael)
- [Gunny](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gunny) (but only until [Broken Steel](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Broken_Steel))
- [Irving Gallows](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Irving_Gallows)
- [Owyn Lyons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Owyn_Lyons)
- [Reginald Rothchild](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Reginald_Rothchild)
- [Sarah Lyons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sarah_Lyons) (unless you decide to do something about the citadel.)
- [Vargas](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vargas) (only during [Following in His Footsteps](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Following_in_His_Footsteps))

Comment: Is Elder Lyons essential, or no? (I outfitted him with some heavy-duty power armor so I could steal his robe sometime back ... )

Comment: Yes, Elder Owyn Lyons is also essential. (I don't know why I missed him, but he is added now.)