# Is it possible to kill everyone or are some NPCs unkillable? 

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Is it possible to kill every last person (and non-person) in Fallout New Vegas? Or are some NPCs unkillable?

Not that I would advocate or condone such a monstrous action, just idle curiosity.

Comment: Lol I'm going to try it on one play-through, from what I've seen I think they're all killable, but could be wrong here. I did get into the strip by killing the robots instead of paying.

Comment: If you've played Fallout 3 as well, you may also be interested in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6518/58). I for one am glad that mass slaughter is an option in New Vegas; while I'll save it for my final playthrough, I do plan on taking *full* advantage of it!

Comment: Reminds of the time I made a guy with 10 strength, 10 endurance, 10 luck, and 0 everything else, gave him the cannibal perk and ate my way through the wasteland.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Yes.**

Unlike *Fallout 3*, no NPC's have 'plot armor' or are otherwise permanently flagged as 'Essential'. You can kill every NPC in the game according to the developers, save one. In fact, it was reported before release that one of the pre-release playtests consisted of a run through in which noone was spared. The final body count reportedly clocked in somewhere around 2500-3000 kills.

That said, there are, technically, 3 exceptions.

1. **The Gun Runners Vendor-Tron** outside Freeside cannot be killed because he is behind a wall that cannot be passed without using the console to no-clip through. He is 'killable', but he is unreachable, rendering that fact moot. However, he is also a robot.
2. **Yes Man** technically can not be killed. If killed he will simply respawn. This is explained in that he is not actually a *specific* Securitron, but rather a program (more like a virus really), that can run on *any* Securitron, and if the one which he currently inhabits is destroyed, he will just download into a new body. Yes Man is the 'only character that cannot be killed' that the devs bragged about, because he is required to trigger the final quest. If all other paths fail, *'Wild Card'* is the fallback.
3. **Children**, such as those found in Freeside, can not be harmed or killed, at all, ever.

Comment: Sweet I'm so doing this :), I wonder what approach is best. I guess leaving the Gun runners around, will let you sell everything to the bot till the end.

Comment: It should be noted that [someone has made a mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/52162/?) to allow killable children. So if you do in fact want to murder absolutely everybody in the wasteland, modders have you covered.

Comment: You cannot kill vendortron, it you `tcl` to him, he is unbeatable.

Answer (score 10):

I have not yet finished the game, but thus far I have killed (and eaten) every single person I have come across.  While this course of action has resulted in many failed missions, it really is fun.  I do plan on actually playing through the game once I finish my genocidal run as a madman named Eli (who looks surprisingly like Denzel Washington, right down to the sunglasses) who carries around a scorched pre-war book everywhere he goes.

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Meat_of_Champions

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Eew!

Comment: rofl +1 for eaten