# Can I kill everybody?

Tags: deus-ex

In Deus-Ex, I'm trying to play a run wherein the main character is a cruel, merciless cyborg who cannot distinguish between friend and foe. Basically, everybody dies.

Things seemed to be going well in the first mission, where one of my comrades greeted me after I annihilated the enemy's leader and I proceeded to unload a 12 gauge into his lovable face, causing him to keel over and die. I stole his assault rifle and went down the stairs to my next friend, who told me what a great guy I was. I smiled and agreed and stabbed him 37 times in the chest. The only problem is that this didn't kill him; it caused him to get aggravated at me and shoot me with several poisonous darts as a form of comeuppance, rendering me quite dead.

Are there some comrades who simply won't die and who will endure whatever pains I put them through, or do I lack the necessary firepower to eliminate them at this point?

Comment: Perhaps you need to try [crushing them with furniture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QV406DsY1M)?

Comment: A new contender for the title of Gaming's ["that mass murderer"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6518/ramifications-of-mass-slaughter), eh? ♪

Comment: @grace See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10766/killing-everyone-in-the-mojave-wasteland

Comment: @LessPop I originally wanted to pop a quick joke on how it seems that everywhere I'll look on this site, I'll find a mass-murderer, but it seems that [I am indeed surrounded](http://i.imgur.com/i1Z8C.png).

Comment: By far and away the best game for a killing spree is Oblivion. You can kill damn near everyone.

Comment: If you're really serious about being 100% lethal, get ready to spend a lot of time chasing down rats and pigeons. Now if only I could find a way to swat the flies...

Comment: Try to find the best way TO kill everybody like a gun with infinite ammo or a melee weapon that doesn't break.Guns to look for:mini-gun,nuke,plasma gun,and poisonous gas if you can find it.Melee weapons you have to look for:katana,car,tree,people,and the best modded weapon in the game,the moon.

Comment: Well, there IS one thing you can't kill... the vacuum cleaner. (You CAN, however, fence it in with a sofa and some plants, annoy the guards into shooting, duck through the firefight to cause friendly fire, getting some higher-ups in the mess.) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omZE8ozyg-k) (http://www.it-he.org/deus3.htm)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are definitely characters you can't kill, or that you can't kill until certain points in the plot. I'm not sure about *all* of them, but Paul springs to mind in the first mission. I've unloaded a great deal of ammo into him many a time, and he just keeps running around and eventually shoots me to death with a plasma rifle.

Your best bet is to save before you try to kill any main-plot characters, I suppose; hopefully that won't ruin the experience for ya.

Comment: +1, I'm almost certain this is correct. Between many play-throughs and obsessive-compulsive experimentation I've tried both extremes, completely non-lethal and completely lethal. Neither seems possible: the game requires at least one character to die as a result of your actions (maybe two... I can't recall), and certain plot-essential characters are protected.

Comment: I won't name the character, but if it's the one I suspect, I've read that it *is* possible to save him/her - just really tricky to pull off. I certainly never managed it, so can't confirm it, alas.

Comment: @Cyclops There's a question on that: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19502/88