# When should I kill my friends?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

On expert realism mode, if a survivor is incapacitated in the safe room at the end of a level, how much health do they spawn with on the next level? Are they still incapacitated?

I usually kill anyone who's hurt so they can spawn with full health, but this is risky because the safe room door remains open while you're doing it. Incapacitating them would be faster, but it only makes sense to do so if they spawn with full health.

Comment: Did you have to add "in Left 4 Dead 2" to the title?

Comment: @bwarner Not really, removed. Someone can rollback if it's ambiguous.

Comment: I'm probably just too big a fan of the intentionally misleading question titles... =)

Comment: You and @Mana for his Kill Everybody: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13892/can-i-kill-everybody. Violent bunch we have here.

Comment: Gaming SE is haunted by psychopathic maniacs, we are all in danger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a survivor is **dead** when the safe room door is closed, they will return with 50 *permanent* health on the next level.

If a survivor is **incapacitated** when the safe room door is closed, they will return with 30 *temporary* health (the same kind of health received when taking pills or adrenaline) and will no longer be incapacitated.

Therefore, it's always better to kill your friends if they have less than 50 health.

Here is a video demonstrating my answer:

Comment: When a survivor is dead they seem to respawn with 100 health on expert realism. Can you double-check that 50 health claim?

Comment: @thethinman I verified before I posted my answer.  They respawn with 50 health in the safe room on the next level or in closets during a level.  Unless you are talking about Realism Versus, which is completely different.

Comment: I am only talking about expert realism. In realism there are no closet spawns, survivors must be revived with a defibrillator. Maybe I'm being unnecessarily skeptical but are we talking about the same game mode?

Comment: Note that this doesn't apply at all for Versus or Realism Versus modes.  Killing off your allies in Versus lowers your team's score multiplier, plus everyone starts the next round at full health.