# What is the fastest way to level up without killing many people?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

After finishing the game for every possible faction, I'm thinking about playing again from the start, maybe even in hardcore mode. What missions are the best to level-up quickly? By this I mean, what are some easy missions which give out a lot of experience? I don't want to kill a lot of people; I might even try not to kill anybody. Any ideas? I think I will also ignore locks and computers since I've done them all before. In my original playthrough, I made the mistake of doing a lot of side missions, so I lost the ability to level-up quickly.

Comment: Being ["Well Rested"](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Well_rested) infers a +10% bonus to all experience gained, so is probably handy to try and keep active.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going through a similar action myself right now -- I'm trying to kill as few humans as possible. (I made an exception for Benny, and raiders who attack on sight.)

Skills: I know you said you don't want to do locks and computers, but you'll have to for some things, so keep lockpicking and science high. Prioritize speech -- you can get out of a lot of fights, and even better, get XP for it. Maybe go for survival and/or repair, and go after the [challenges](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_challenges) for crafting.

So some early-game missions to help you out? Skip Primm entirely, head straight to Mojave Outpost. You'll get Ghost's quest there, which just requires you to go to Nipton. In Nipton, you'll get "Cold, Cold Heart," which just requires you to go to Mojave. Easy, non-violent 250 XP. Not much, but it'll get you started.

From there, make a beeline to New Vegas, by way of Novac. In Novac, do Boone's side quest, because it's quick and easy and non-violent. In Freeside, take the peaceful route through G.I. Blues, hook up the Followers and the Garretts, and do the Wang Dang Atomic Tango. Once in New Vegas, go talk to Mr. House and deal with Ring-a-Ding-Ding. After that, you should be able to take down Talent Pool pretty quickly and peacefully.

By the time you get through all this, with perhaps a little bit of minor side adventurism, and you should be at least level 10 or 12.

Comment: thanks for sharing some cool ideas, I think I might just try to tour the whole map(if im able to get the animal friend perk I wont have to fight animals :) My goals are to see find some new and cool quests and to get uber luck for achievements.

Comment: Boone's quest requires you to lead somebody to their death, hardly non-violent.

Comment: @kotekzot: I have a loose definition of non-violent. See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6518/58 (I've forgotten, apparently, how to write in Markdown.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure what the fastest way is to level up without killing people. I provided a link below with all the quests possible in fallout:NV. As you can imagine there is an enormous amount of side quests, you may want to read through them and determine which ones involve no killing.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_quests

Comment: Note that this link contains spoilers

Answer (score 1):

There is a way where you need only kill about seven people and you may reach level 30 before even leaving Goodsprings.

1. Do the tutorial mission, then go see Trudy
2. Talk to Cobb and ask if he needs help taking over the town. Go and kill Ringo in the gas station
3. Go to Cobb and tell him Ringo is dead
4. Cobb will ask you to shake down Chet... DON'T!
5. Kill Cobb and his friends and then go to Chet
6. Tell him the Powder Gangers need supplies and with a speech or barter check of 25 or higher you can keep asking him and reaching level 30 before leaving Goodsprings

Comment: Step 6 is an exploit, I don't think that's what he meant.

Comment: @Ragnar better to have options ;) its boring to do the same missions again :(

Answer (score 0):

First, do all tutorials and Run, Goodsprings Run.

Carry on with the Powder Ganger storyline and when the time comes defect to the NCR. In the Primm Sheriff thing, get it run by NCR and stick to the roads. Wipe out the gas station in the middle. Then do all of the NCR missions at the outpost and get ED-E with spare supplies.

Go to do Cold, Cold Heart but quickly kill the group. Clear out the town hall and proceed to Old World Blues. I came out a level 17 with a stealth suit and a HUGE gun.

After getting Boone, completing the Sierra Madre and finishing Saving Camp Forlorn Hope (On the coast)

Go to Zion. Then hit New Vegas and go NCR. I skipped about 30-50 missions through NCR Support but finished level 29. Do the Divide too.

A less violent option is to try and use stealth; then you'll get into nearly no fights and still have a lot of quests to do. A good tip (if you get to the Vegas Strip) is to take up the White Glove Society quest line and go non-cannibalism; a few thousand XP for only 3 kills minimum, I believe, and they're already hostile. Get a good gun first, though; one enemy has good armor.

Comment: Be careful going into Old World Blues early (hardcore on/level hard). I did and ended up being so overwhelmed I had to revert to an early save. After going back in at level 17 I'm still having trouble, but it's better than last time.

Comment: So your advice for leveling up without killing many people is to kill many people. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to New Vegas and do all the quests there. The only problem is getting there, because there are Deathclaws on the way and you need 2000 caps to get in (or a fake ID at Mick and Ralphs in Freeside for 500 caps and a speech check).

- To bypass the Deathclaws, stick to the right side scaling the mountains all the way.
- To get the money easily try:

  - Taking (not stealing) all the items in every place you go to.
  - Placing a bet in a custom Deathclaw vs 3 giant radscorpions battle - it costs 500 but you get 620 if you win, and if you lose you can just re-load the game.
  - Go find [The Thorn](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Thorn) and fight in it.

I managed to get into New Vegas in about an hour from the game start and still in level 1, and the New Vegas quests give thousands of XP.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple and easy way for you to make some easy xp. Go to Cottonwood Cove, but **only** if you are on good terms with the legion and look for the a tall building right before the shore. Go upstairs and look for the centurion and talk to him. You will need barter 35 for the speech option. Just keep doing it without killing him. Make sure you don't take Boone with you.